# Postgres type "{field type}" is only a shell

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, postgis

I use Django & postgres. My migration contains something like this :

```
db.create_table('location_locationlevel', (
        ('id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
        ('name_0', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)),
        ('name_1', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)),
        ('name_2', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)),
        ('name_3', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)),
        ('name_4', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)),
        ('geom', self.gf('django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.MultiPolygonField')()),
    ))
```

When I run migration, I get error like below:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: type "geometry" is only a shell
LINE 1: ...ABLE public.location_locationlevel ADD COLUMN geom geometry 
                                                         ^
QUERY:  ALTER TABLE public.location_locationlevel ADD COLUMN geom geometry 
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer)
```

Did anyone have experienced something like this before, and what was the solution?

Answer (score 4):

In short, you need to reinstall postgis, possibly just `drop extension postgis;` and `create extension postgis;`.

### Longer explanation

You could possibly be missing just this type, but I doubt it is just that, tho if you want to try, here is from 2.3:

```
CREATE TYPE public.geometry
   (INPUT=geometry_in,
       OUTPUT=geometry_out,
       RECEIVE=geometry_recv,
       SEND=geometry_send,
       TYPMOD_IN=geometry_typmod_in,
       TYPMOD_OUT=geometry_typmod_out,
       ANALYZE=geometry_analyze,
       CATEGORY='U', DEFAULT='',
       INTERNALLENGTH=-1, ALIGNMENT=double, STORAGE=MAIN);
ALTER TYPE public.geometry
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON TYPE public.geometry
  IS 'postgis type: Planar spatial data type.';
```

As for what shells, you can read more about them in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html).

*In short*:
Some types require functions that in turn require that type with is to be declared, so neither can be created - normally.

In order to workaround that problem, Postgres will create shell types that are pretty much placeholder just to satisfy validation.

In your case `geometry` is shell type and was not properly declared, with means that postgis was not installed correctly.

Shell type looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE public.geometry
   (INPUT=shell_in,
       OUTPUT=shell_out,
       RECEIVE=-,
       SEND=-,
       ANALYZE=-,
       CATEGORY='P',
    PASSEDBYVALUE, DEFAULT='',
       INTERNALLENGTH=4, ALIGNMENT=int4, STORAGE=PLAIN);
ALTER TYPE public.geometry
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And function requiring shell type could be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geometry_in(cstring)
    RETURNS geometry
    AS '$libdir/postgis-2.3','LWGEOM_in'
    LANGUAGE 'c' IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE;
```

If you look back at proper `geometry` definition you will notice that this function is part of it, but not in this shell.