# unable to create postgis extension after migration from Postgres 9 to 13

Tags: postgresql, postgis

We are in the process of migrating our main production database from Postgres 9.2.4 to Postgres 13.2. We did a pg_dump/pg_restore of the database to its new server and found that a total of 6 tables (out of 99) did not seem to make it to their new location. When trying to dump the individual tables and then restore them, we encountered the following error:

```
[user@server ~]$ psql -U db_user db_name < /home/pmena/tmp/missing_table_1.dump
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
ERROR:  type "geometry" is only a shell
LINE 2:     locationlonlat geometry,
                           ^
ERROR:  relation "db_user.missing_table_1" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "missing_table_1" does not exist
invalid command \.
ERROR:  relation "missing_table_1" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "missing_table_1" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "missing_table_1" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "missing_table_1" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "missing_table_1" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "missing_table_1" does not exist
```

A search of Stack Overflow articles like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055852/postgres-type-field-type-is-only-a-shell) pointed to a missing postgis extension. I then tried to drop and recreate the extension, but stumbled into another error:

```
db_name=# drop extension postgis;
ERROR:  extension "postgis" does not exist
db_name=# create extension postgis;
ERROR:  relation "spatial_ref_sys" already exists
```

So now it seems that some component of the postgis extension, `spatial_ref_sys`, already exists, preventing me from creating the extension as suggested. Then again, if spatial_ref_sys is already there without it, is their an alternate way to provide the `geometry` type?

And here's the question I wish I didn't have to ask: is the jump from Postres 9 to 13 too ambitious? We've invested a little over a month into Postgres 13 and have found no issues until attempting to utilize this subset of functionality.

As always, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the database, re-create it, `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` in it and then restore the dump. There might be errors restoring `spatial_ref_sys` from the dump, but that should be ok.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! What we did instead of dropping the entire database was to drop the spatial_ref_sys table, create the postgis extension, and then restore "missing_table_1", which completed successfully. The other five tables then restored successfully.